# Java - Метод getSource() в слушателях

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть класс, который создает окно и закрепляет на этом окне кнопки. Именно поэтому мне нужно создать слушателей для этих самых кнопок. И я решил, что слушатель будет один. Он будет сам распознавать какая именно была нажата кнопка.

Но вопрос заключается в следующем: Что именно возвращает метод `getSource()`?

```
public class MyListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
       //что хранится в переменной event?
       Object event = ev.getSource();   
       //code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Это же в документации написано. Прежде чем вопрос создавать, стоит сперва к ней обращаться.

Comment: @iksuy   Начнем с того,что это форум.Поэтому я могу задавать любые вопросы,которые связаны с программированием.

Comment: В общем то это не форум, а Q&A - здесь другие правила, но вопросы вы действительно тут задавать имеете полное право

Comment: @SlandShow, разумеется можете, я же не написал что нельзя, я лишь дал рекомендацию, которая поможет вам расти, как профессионалу.

Answer (score 4):

getSource() возвращает ссылку на объект, от которого пришло событие
[пруф](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Просто явно преобразуйте объект getSource();

```
JButton btn=(JButton) e.getSource();
```

А дальше работайте как с объектом-кнопкой. Я так понял, что вы искали ответ именно на этот вопрос. А getSourse() и вправду возвращает объект источника события Event.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но зачем? Уже прошло достаточно много времени с того момента как я задал этот вопрос.

Comment: Дело в том, что на такую проблему и на эту ссылку могут натолкнуться другие юные программисты)) Так что я скорее им помог, чем вам